# GWT: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have a GWT app that works fine with one computer (Windows 10), the code is hosted in Bitbucket, and the other copy on another PC is not working (Windows 7)

The error is:

```
[INFO] com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:2060)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:2045)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.MinimalRebuildCacheManager.syncReadDiskCache(MinimalRebuildCacheManager.java:258)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.MinimalRebuildCacheManager.getCache(MinimalRebuildCacheManager.java:98)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.doCompile(Recompiler.java:350)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:168)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.recompile(Recompiler.java:127)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.recompile(Outbox.java:128)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.recompile(JobRunner.java:113)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.access$000(JobRunner.java:37)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner$2.run(JobRunner.java:90)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2449)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1385)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.MinimalRebuildCacheManager$2.call(MinimalRebuildCacheManager.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.MinimalRebuildCacheManager$2.call(MinimalRebuildCacheManager.java:156)
[INFO]  ... 4 more
[INFO]       [WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

I've been trying to fix this for hours but I am not able to fix. I've tried copying the folder as in into the other machine still not working, also did a clean `git clone` then run `mvn clean gwt:run -Pjboss7 -U` and still not working.

The version of GWT my app is using is `2.8.0-beta1`

What could be the root cause of this error?

Comment: Have you tried deleting all temporary files? (in your profile's Temp folder)

Comment: Are both computers running the same version of Java?